# How to write a jquery function for same-type controls in html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i'm designing a form which gets user information and then go another page. There's lots of "input text" controls to fill. User must fill all "input text" controls in order to go home page. if a control is empty, an "x" icon should be put inside "input text".

My main problem is, i'm new at jquery and i dont want to write this function for every control:

```
$('#send').click(function () {
            if ($('#kname').val().length == 0) {
                $('#kname').css({ background: "url(image/error.png) no-repeat right" });
            }
        });
```

i need a general function for all controls. here is my html lines:

```
   //some code
       <input type="text" id="knumber" />
        <input type="text" id="kname" />
        <input type="text" id="ksurname" />
   //some other code
```

edit: i'm using an "input button" to send these info.

```
<input type="button" value="Send Them" id="send" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to validate all input elements with type `text` as given below

```
$("input[type=text]").filter(function() {
    return $.trim(this.value).length == 0
}).css({
    background : "url(image/error.png) no-repeat right"
});
```

or add a class to those elements which you wish to validate like `not-empty` then

```
<input id="kname" type="text" class="not-empty" />
<input id="ksurname" type="text" class="not-empty" />
```

then

```
$(".not-empty").filter(function() {
    return $.trim(this.value).length == 0
}).css({
    background : "url(image/error.png) no-repeat right"
});
```

Comment: @AliSağırvelioğulları better if you delete the other question

Answer (score 3):

What about using [$.each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) and looping through all the text elemnts

```
$('#send').click(function () {
       $("input[type=text]").each(function(){
            if ($(this).val() == '') {
                $(this).css({ background: "url(image/error.png) no-repeat right" });
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

how about?

```
$("#send").click(function() {
     $("input[type=text]").each(function(){
          if ($(this).val().length == 0) {
               $(this).css({ background: "url(image/error.png) no-repeat right" });
          }
     });
});
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/ddDSB/

Answer (score 0):

```
//some code
<input class="validate" type="text" id="knumber" />
<input class="validate" type="text" id="kname" />
<input class="validate"type="text" id="ksurname" />
//some code...


$(".validate").click(function(){
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try using this
add a class name "requiredField" to all your text fields

in your button click method find all the textboxes

```
textboxes = $('#formid').find('.requiredField');
```

then use each method.

```
textboxes.each(function() {
 if(this.value.length==0){
   $('#kname').css({ background: "url(image/error.png) no-repeat right" });
    //do something here
}
}
```

Comment: should i write this method into my button's click event?

Comment: @AliSağırvelioğulları yes, i mentioned it in the second line